# incrementing numbers starting with zero in pseudo element followed by line

Tags: css

Is it possible to create something like on the picture I attached? [image]
I have ::before element on h2 tag but I don't know how to add those numbers, they should also increment on every section [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZLc2Y.png): https://i.stack.imgur.com/toKe1.png

Code ([fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0oxybdaq/8/))

```css
.page-section h2 {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 2rem;
}

.page-section h2::before {
  content: '';
  height: 0.4rem;
  width: 25%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1rem;
  left: 0;
  background: #ef4a24;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="field-items">
  <section class="page-section">
    <h2 class="text title-text" id="section-1">Introduction</h2>
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: i update my answer.. please check again.. maybe your problem solve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make use of CSS `counter` like this. Simply set the counter into the `field-items` div and then use a `::before` pseudo element to add the counter to your `h2`. And an `::after` pseudo element to add the line.

```css
body {
  font-size: 18pt;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.field-items {
  counter-reset: section;
}

.page-section h2 {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 1.8em;
}

.page-section h2::before {
  counter-increment: section;
  content: counter(section, decimal-leading-zero);
  font-size: 0.5em;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #ef4a24;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1.7em;
  left: 0;
}

.page-section h2::after {
  content: '';
  height: 10px;
  width: 25%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1em;
  left: 1em;
  background: #ef4a24;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="field-items">
  <section class="page-section">
    <h2 class="text title-text" id="section-1">Introduction</h2>
  </section>
  <section class="page-section">
    <h2 class="text title-text" id="section-2">Main Story</h2>
  </section>
  <section class="page-section">
    <h2 class="text title-text" id="section-3">Epilogue</h2>
  </section>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```css
  

.page-section h2 {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 2rem;
  counter-increment: headerCounter;
}

.page-section h2::before {

   content: counter(headerCounter) ".";
  counter-increment: h2;
  content: counter(headerCounter, decimal-leading-zero);
  width: 25%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1rem;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  font-size: 0.5em;
  color: #ef4a24;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, transparent 2em, currentColor 2em);
  background 
}
```

```html
<div class="field-items">
  <section class="page-section">
    <h2 class="text title-text" id="section-1">Introduction</h2>
  </section>

  <section class="page-section">
    <h2 class="text title-text" id="section-1">Other things</h2>
  </section>
   <section class="page-section">
    <h2 class="text title-text" id="section-1">Other things</h2>
  </section>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [CSS counter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Lists_and_Counters/Using_CSS_counters) as the content of your `::before` element. You can create the line using a `linear-gradient`, and then change it's height using `background-size` and positioning it to the center vertically:

```css
body {
  counter-reset: headerCounter;
}

.page-section h2 {
  position: relative;
  counter-increment: headerCounter;
}

.page-section h2::before {
  display: block;
  content: counter(headerCounter, decimal-leading-zero);
  font-size: 0.6em;
  color: #ef4a24;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, transparent 2em, currentColor 2em) no-repeat;
  background-size: 25% 4px;
  background-position: left center;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="field-items">
  <section class="page-section">
    <h2 class="text title-text" id="section-1">Introduction</h2>
  </section>

  <section class="page-section">
    <h2 class="text title-text" id="section-1">Other things</h2>
  </section>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

No, this is only possible with pure CSS if you use ordered lists (`<ol>`), which is something that shouldn't be done for headings, and even then, you wouldn't be able to get a zero before digits.

Therefore, I don't recommend using pseudo-elements for this. This is better accomplished with a `<span>` with `display: block;`.